# Do users get notified when their answer is being deleted?

Tags: discussion

Today a new user posted a silly comment as an answer, I flagged it and Kortuk appropriately deleted it (it was too silly to convert to a comment, really). Does this guy get a notification of this? Otherwise I'm afraid he'll post similar things. And most users can't see the deleted answers, but I can, and that's not always a plus.

Comment: Make a silly answer (here) and I'll be happy to delete it for you as a test.

Comment: There is a feature that a moderator message will notify through that but I believe yours did, best way is to make a test here.

Comment: @stevenvh, please post a comment on m.Alin's answer and then flag me to delete it right away. I will delete it and we will see if he receives a notification.

Answer (score 2):

No, users are not notified of a delete. If a moderator places a comment on the question and then deletes it this will still appear in their inbox, otherwise they had no notice of this action. For science we verified with a moderator comment and ensured all operated as normal. With a moderator comment:
[image: User post deleted while having 100 rep and can see the post that was deleted and received inbox notification.]

But this would not occur from a user such as stevenvh whom has high enough rep that he was performing moderation, just without the star. [This is currently a discussion point on meta.SO, Show some support if you would like the feature also.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133729/treat-comments-on-deleted-posts-from-moderating-users-like-comments-from-diamond)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't receive any notification about my answer being deleted.

But I can see my deleted answer:
[image]

Comment: You can always see your own answers, also deleted ones. Once you have 10k rep you can see *all* deleted answers, which, like I said is not always a pretty sight. A lot of rubbish at the bottom of pages. Personally I don't see the need for it.

Comment: @m.Alin, Did you receive an inbox notification for Clabacchio's comment?

Comment: @Kortuk I did, but that comment was before my answer got deleted.

Comment: @m.Alin, that is interesting.

Comment: @Kortuk Interesting because one doesn't receive any notification that one's answer got deleted or interesting for some other reason?

Comment: @m.Alin, there is not notification that your answer is deleted, I know a mod comment will notify through a delete, but that is an intended feature I was notified of a long time ago. Just need to make sure I note on the comments myself.

Comment: @Kortuk - Just a remark: I don't see the line "Why was your post deleted..." below in the actual deleted post. Is that OK? Or did you delete that mod comment in the deleted post? (This is getting complicated!!)

Comment: @stevenvh - The screenshot was made by m.Alin, who sees a link to the FAQ section on deletion.  That's not a comment, it's generated by the system and shown to the OP only.  There are no deleted comments from mods or anyone else.